# Output is empty when perform a seed in nWidart Laravel

Tags: laravel, module, package, seed

I'm using nWidart package to manager Laravel app using modules.

I perform a migrate on Settings module.

`php artisan module:make-migration create_locations_table Settings`

`php artisan module:migrate Settings`

It's ok!

When I make a seeder:

`php artisan module:make-seed Locations Settings` => It worked!

But: `php artisan module:seed Settings`

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Settings\Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class LocationsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();
//        $this->call("OthersTableSeeder");
        $data = [
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Hà Nội',
            'parent_id' => NULL,
            'type' => '1',
            'district_id' => NULL,
            'province_id' => NULL,
            'country_id' => '79162',
            'created_at' => '2020-03-26 12:01:08',
            'updated_at' => '2020-03-26 12:01:08'
        ];
        DB::table('locations')->insert($data);
    }
}
```

The output is empty!

[image]

I think it doesn't go to the LocationsTableSeeder file because when I try `dd(1)` on it, the output is empty too

Can you help me?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried doing `composer dump-autoload` then do the seed again?

Comment: @JulioMotol, Yes, I tried it but the output is still empty

Comment: What is the version of your `laravel\framework` and `nWidart\laravel-modules`?

Comment: @JulioMotol `"laravel/framework": "5.7.*"` and `"nwidart/laravel-modules": "^3.2.0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `laravel/framework 5.7.*`, you might want to install `nwidart/laravel-modules ^4.0` as it is the proper version for you laravel version. See [compatibilty](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/tree/4.0.0#laravel-modules).

If that still doesn't work, do this for the meantime:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=Modules\Settings\Database\Seeders\LocationsTableSeeder
```

> #### Way forward
>
> Since your project is pretty far behind. I doubt that they will provide any support for this anymore. Upgrading your laravel to `^7.x` and laravel-modules to `^7.0` may fix this since there had been an [issue about this](https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/823) and has been fixed in the latest versions.

Comment: I tried your command and successfully. Maybe I will try to update laravel-modules and test it. Thanks so much :D